# Using ROW_NUMBER() Over to find closest date match to 0 or earlier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a need to compare all the recorded dates in one column to a deadline date in the other column. I can do a ROW_NUMBER() OVER to find the closest date, however, I cannot go past the deadline date. I know I can add in the WHERE clause "WHERE recorded_date <= deadline_date", but I need to show all the data for auditing purposes.

Here is the CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE Vitals (
Player  nvarchar(50),
Vital   nvarchar(20),
Val int,
Entry_Date  datetime,
Game_Date datetime
);
```

Here is the INSERT Values:

```
INSERT INTO Vitals (Player, Vital, Val, Entry_Date, Game_Date)

VALUES

('George', 'Weight', 227, '20230525 12:02:10', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 226, '20230421 16:10:22', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 227, '20230508 14:27:01', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 228, '20230527 08:45:55', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 230, '20230601 11:42:23', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 229, '20230605 17:07:27', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 223, '20230612 07:30:02', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 228, '20230601 18:10:05', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 229, '20230524 10:15:19', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 228, '20230506 11:20:13', '6/1/23 20:00:00'),
('George', 'Weight', 230, '20230602 16:18:33', '6/1/23 20:00:00')
```

Here is the SQL Code I am currently using:

```
SELECT
 Player
,Vital
,Val
,Entry_Date
,Game_Date
,DATEDIFF(DAY, Game_Date, Entry_Date) 'Days Diff'
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Player ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, Game_Date, Entry_Date)) ASC) RN

FROM Vitals;
```

Here is what I am I trying to achieve:

| Player | Vital | Val | Entry_Date | Game_Date | Days Diff | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Weight | 228 | 6/1/23 18:10 | 6/1/23 20:00 | 0 | 1 |
| George | Weight | 230 | 6/1/23 11:42 | 6/1/23 20:00 | 0 | 2 |
| George | Weight | 228 | 5/27/23 8:45 | 6/1/23 20:00 | -5 | 3 |
| George | Weight | 227 | 5/25/23 12:02 | 6/1/23 20:00 | -7 | 4 |
| George | Weight | 229 | 5/24/23 10:15 | 6/1/23 20:00 | -8 | 5 |
| George | Weight | 227 | 5/8/23 14:27 | 6/1/23 20:00 | -24 | 6 |
| George | Weight | 228 | 5/6/23 11:20 | 6/1/23 20:00 | -26 | 7 |
| George | Weight | 226 | 4/21/23 16:10 | 6/1/23 20:00 | -41 | 8 |
| George | Weight | 230 | 6/2/23 16:18 | 6/1/23 20:00 | 1 | 9 |
| George | Weight | 229 | 6/5/23 17:07 | 6/1/23 20:00 | 4 | 10 |
| George | Weight | 223 | 6/12/23 7:30 | 6/1/23 20:00 | 10 | 11 |

As you can see, the row numbering is first ordering the Entry Dates **BEFORE** Game Date first then ordering the dates after the Game Date (missed the deadline, but have to show by how much to auditors). I have tried different ways to use Case statements in the Order By, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

p.s., Note the difference between row number 1 and 2. Number 1 is very close to game time. I need to order closest to game time as possible.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Why 5/25/2023 should show first? What makes it before 4/21 or 6/12? What is the logic there? And BTW that is not the result of that SQL.

Comment: I created a fiddle for you. Please explain what you want to achieve based on that one.  https://dbfiddle.uk/RsezEIdq

Comment: @CetinBasoz - No, June 1st at 18:10 should be first.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - I thank you very kindly for the Fiddle help. I edited my SQL there to test it and edited here. I need to make a bookmark for this Fiddle - it's great! 

Anyway - I am trying to order the results, first by all the dates ON or BEFORE the Game Date then by the dates after Game Date. The requirement is to do do the weight within 3 days before game time.  But we have constant weights being entered so we want to track that, but the officials want the weight within 72 hours of game time with the weight reported as close to game time as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with myData as 
(
    SELECT  Player
       ,Vital
       ,Val
       ,Entry_Date
       ,Game_Date
       ,DATEDIFF(DAY, Game_Date, Entry_Date) 'Diff'
    FROM Vitals
)
select Player
    ,Vital
    ,Val
    ,Entry_Date
    ,Game_Date
    ,Diff as 'Days Diff'
    ,Row_Number() over (Partition by Player
                        Order by case when Diff <= 0 then -1 else 1 end, abs(Diff)
                       ) as RN
from myData;
```

Here is [DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_Of7J1mE)

| Player | Vital | Val | Entry_Date | Game_Date | Days Diff | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Weight | 228 | 2023-06-01 18:10:05.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | 0 | 1 |
| George | Weight | 230 | 2023-06-01 11:42:23.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | 0 | 2 |
| George | Weight | 228 | 2023-05-27 08:45:55.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | -5 | 3 |
| George | Weight | 227 | 2023-05-25 12:02:10.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | -7 | 4 |
| George | Weight | 229 | 2023-05-24 10:15:19.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | -8 | 5 |
| George | Weight | 227 | 2023-05-08 14:27:01.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | -24 | 6 |
| George | Weight | 228 | 2023-05-06 11:20:13.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | -26 | 7 |
| George | Weight | 226 | 2023-04-21 16:10:22.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | -41 | 8 |
| George | Weight | 230 | 2023-06-02 16:18:33.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | 1 | 9 |
| George | Weight | 229 | 2023-06-05 17:07:27.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | 4 | 10 |
| George | Weight | 223 | 2023-06-12 07:30:02.000 | 2023-06-01 20:00:00.000 | 11 | 11 |

Comment: Thank you @CetinBasoz - such an elegant solution and it works perfectly with my huge dataset I have to process. Much appreciated!